# Liquibase : issue with setting boolean default value

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to add a new field with liquibase

```
<addColumn tableName="contact_client">
            <column defaultValue="0"
                    defaultValueBoolean="0"
                    name="obsolete"
                    type="boolean"/>
        </addColumn>
```

But I am getting this error :

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for
>   'obsolete' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE myApp.contact_client ADD obsolete
>   BIT(1) DEFAULT 'false' NULL]

How can I pass a default value?

Comment: I guess you are using mySQL? The error message is from your DB. Although liquibase of course created the SQL. You could try to figure out what is wrong the the generated SQL by running it manually on your DB. (Maybe without the single quotes on `DEFAULT false`?) And when you know what is going wrong maybe look for an already repoted error in [liquibase jira](https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues/CORE-3217?filter=allopenissues). Or just change the values of your changelog `defaultValue="0"` to something else (thoug I doubt that the 0 value is the problem).

Answer (score 25):

Actually, here is the solution for a MySQL database:

```xml
<addColumn tableName="contact_client">
    <column defaultValueBoolean="false"
            name="obsolete"
            type="boolean"/>
</addColumn>
```

I needed to remove the defaultValue property.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me, thanks to this [link](https://forum.jmix.io/t/default-value-for-column/399/4), I added the **addNotNullConstraint** as a next **changeSet**

```
<changeSet id="1000001" author="some_author">
    <addColumn tableName="some_table">
        <column name="some_column" type="boolean"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="1000002" author="some_author">
    <addNotNullConstraint 
        tableName="some_table" 
        columnName="some_column"
        columnDataType="boolean"
        validate="true"
        defaultNullValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `defaultValue="0"`

**Source code :**

[image]

**Database value :**

[image]

**NB: I'm using SQL Serve**

[image]

***Hope this will be helpful***